# Powershell String format fails to add hex prefix when looping

Tags: powershell, string-formatting

Ciao all -

I'm using Powershell 7.2 to automate some hardware configuration through the hardware's CLI.
I am using a loop to generate strings that include "0x" prefixes to express hex bytes, but having an issue where any consecutive iterations after the first pass of the loop do not print the "0x" prefix.

The following will produce the issue:

```
function fTest($id)
{
    foreach($n in @(1, 2, 3)) 
    {
        write-host $id.gettype()
        write-host ("{0:x}" -f $id)
        $id++
    }
}

fTest 0x1a
```

Actual output:

```
System.Int32
0x1a
System.Int32
1b
System.Int32
1c
```

The `0x`prefixes are omitted in iters 2 and 3.

- Why is this happening?
- What is a clean way to correct the issue?

I'm a PowerShell noob, so I am happy to receive suggestions or examples of entirely different approaches.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `'0x{0:x2}' -f $id`. If you don't tell it to write out `0x`, it will not automagically prefix that to the actual hex number

Comment: But it automatically prefixes it on the first pass of the loop. ```0x1a```, ```1b``` etc

Comment: The problem with just `'0x{0:x}' -f $id` is that the first will be print as `0x0x1a` so to resolve the problem cast id into int like that `'0x{0:x}'-f [int] $id`

Comment: The first time you send it `0x1a` which is interpreted as string. Try sending it the decimal value `16`. Cast the parameter to int: `fTest([int]$id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Type-constrain your `$p` parameter to *unambiguously* make it a *number* (integer), as [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) suggests:

  - `function fTest($id)` -> `function fTest([int] $id)`
- Build the `0x` prefix into the format string passed to `-f`:

  - `"{0:x}" -f $id` -> `'0x{0:x}' -f $id`

---

Building on the helpful comments:

> Why is this happening?

- Format string `{0:x}`, when applied to a *number*, only ever produces a hexadecimal representation *without* a `0x` prefix; e.g.:

  ```
   PS> '{0:x}' -f 10
   a   # NOT '0xa'
  ```

  - If the operand is *not* a number, the numeric `:x` specification is *ignored*:

    ```
     PS> '{0:x}' -f 'foo'
     foo
    ```
- The problem in your case is related to **how PowerShell handles arguments passed to parameters that are not type-constrained**:

  - Argument `0x1a` is *ambiguous*: it could be a *number* - expressed as hexadecimal constant `0x1a`, equivalent to decimal `26` - or a *string*.

    - While in *expression*-parsing mode this ambiguity would *not* arise (strings must be quoted there), it does in *argument*-parsing mode, where quoting around strings is optional (except if the string contains metacharacters) - see the conceptual [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) topic.
  - What PowerShell does in this case is to create **a *hybrid* argument value: The value is parsed *as a number*, but it *caches its original string representation*** behind the scenes, which is used for display formatting, for instance:

    ```
    PS> & { param($p) $p; $p.ToString() } 0x1a
    0x1a  # With default output formatting, the original string form is used.
    26    # $p is an [int], so .ToString() yields its decimal representation
    ```
- As of PowerShell 7.2.2, surprisingly and problematically, **in the context of `-f`**, the [string-formatting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), such **a hybrid value is treated *as a string*, even though it self-reports *as a number***:

  ```
  PS> & { param($p) $p.GetType().FullName; '{0:N2}' -f $p } 0x1a
  System.Int32  # $p is of type [int] == System.Int32
  0x1a          # !! With -f $p is unexpectedly treated *as a string*,
                # !! yielding the cached original string representation.
  ```

  - This unexpected behavior has been reported in [GitHub issue #17199](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17199).
- *Type-constraining* the parameter to which such a hybrid argument is passed, as shown at the top, avoids the ambiguity: on invocation, the argument is converted to an unwrapped instance of the parameter's type (see next point).
- As for **why the output changed starting with the 2nd iteration**:

  - The cached string representation is implemented by way of an invisible `[psobject]` wrapper around the instance of the numeric type stored in `$id`, in this case.
  - When you update this value by way of an increment operation (`++`), the `[psobject]` wrapper is *lost*, and the variable is updated with an unwrapped number (the original value + 1).
  - Therefore, starting with the 2nd iteration, `$id` contained an unwrapped `[int]` instance, resulting in the `{0:x}` number format being honored and therefore yielding a hexadecimal representation *without* a `0x` prefix.
  - The only reason the 1st iteration yielded a `0x` prefix was that it was present in the original string representation of the argument; as stated above, the *numeric* `:x` format specifier was *ignored* in this case, given that the `-f` operand was (unexpectedly) treated as a *string*.

Comment: This is some nice detective work.

Comment: I have one or two answers (mainly C# or SQL) like this, but needing this level of detail is rare. But for 10 years now I've been more sysadmin than developer, and I **wish** my powershell was at this level. I don't relish the frustration one must endure to get there.

Comment: Thanks, @Joel. Yes, sparing others such frustrations by at least _documenting_ the pitfalls is part of what motivates my answers. Of course, the better solution would be to fix the language to remove those pitfalls, but my efforts there have been less successful... (I do get the opposing force of wanting to remain backward-compatible). Let's see what happens in this case: [GitHub issue #17199](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17199)

Comment: Totally agree with @JoelCoehoorn. Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: I suspected something like a 'hybrid' type state causing an Int32 to behave like a string, but as Joel put it, I was dreading the 'frustration to be endured' in order to get to the bottom of understanding. Thanks @mklement0 for the short-cut to the bottom of the issue!